# GEE doesn't export my featurecollection as table with all the features

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv

I have script in GEE which calculates for given geometry (reduceregions) the mean NDVI value for given period of time ans then suppose to export the table as CSV file when the polygon name is the columns ,the rows are the different dates and images, and the values are the mean NDVI value for each polygon for specific date.
For some reason, when I check my result featurecollection I have in each image one polygon, but when I export it I get only the dates without the polygon names and they dissapear so my final excel looks like this:
[image]

I'm also worried because seems like out of 5 polygons (A,B,C,D,E) it gets results only for B,C,D and little  but for A, and I don't know if it has to do with the export -missing-polygons-name-error.

**here is a link to my script+geometry:**

https://code.earthengine.google.com/705aa58c4d43a2da2c073845ee563559

**My end goal: To export my "result featurecollection" with the names off al the polygons and their mean value.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you will get the columns present in your first feature when exporting, unless you specify `selectors`. In your case, the first feature only contains `system:index`, `time` and `.geo`, so that's what you get in your CSV. The below code snippet find out which `Name` properties you've got and include them as `selectors`. It will take a few seconds until this is complete, so the `Run` button will not show up directly among your tasks.

```
// Evaluate properties to export (selectors), then export.
ee.List(triplets
  .distinct('Name')
  .aggregate_array('Name'))
  .cat(['.geo', 'time']) // Append more properties here as needed
  .evaluate(function (selectors) {
    // selectors must be a client-side object, so evaluate first.
    // If you know them up-front, just plug them in when exporting.
    var desc1 = 'table_demo_'
    Export.table.toDrive({
      collection: table1,
      description: desc1,
      fileNamePrefix: desc1,
      fileFormat: 'CSV',
      selectors: selectors
    })
  })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1ba930c4c760724ae55d65099838debb

Comment: Additionally, see these solutions: [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355073/exporting-lst-median-values-of-a-time-series-in-google-ee-to-csv-file/355104#355104)