# GEE: Getting empty columns when mapping over imageCollection with daily images to reduceRegions

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to obtain daily NO2 pollution values for global district areas. I fail to get any of the bands of my images returned as columns. When I reduceRegions over only one image from the collection, I manage to obtain the bands of the image as columns.

Here's the code:

```
var districts = ee.FeatureCollection(gadm);

var no2Days = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2")
  .select('NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2020-04-26', '2020-04-28');

var scaleNo2 = no2Days.first().projection().nominalScale();
print(no2Days.first());

var no2FirstDay = no2Days.first();
print(no2FirstDay);

var no2FirstDayRed = no2FirstDay.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  collection: districts,
  scale: scaleNo2,
 });
print(no2FirstDayRed.limit(5));

var dailyAverage = no2Days.map(function(image){
  var time = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  var districtMeans = image.reduceRegions({
    'reducer': ee.Reducer.mean(),
    'scale': scaleNo2,
    'collection': districts,
  }).map(function(feat){
    return ee.Feature(feat).set('Date', time);
  });
  return districtMeans;
}).flatten();
print(dailyAverage.limit(5));

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: no2FirstDayRed.limit(5),
  description:'no2Test',
  fileFormat: 'csv'
});
```

The script can be found here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/5fd4bda5eb3db4ebd552fc2c66439edc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exporting, the first feature is tested on it's available properties. If they are not present in the first, they won't be exported. You can find solutions [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355073/exporting-lst-median-values-of-a-time-series-in-google-ee-to-csv-file/355104#355104) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359850/gee-doesnt-export-my-featurecollection-as-table-with-all-the-features). This might work for you (note that you did not share your asset, so I am unable to verify):

```
dailyAverage = dailyAverage.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['NO2_column_number_density']));
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a7902fc05257ca1553398f14078d8f2c)

Comment: This works great, thank you so much. I've now shared the asset. Any hunch, why there are null values?

Also, would you have any advice how to select bands early on? I'd like to select 'NO2_column_number_density', but it gives me computation timeouts, when I print it.

Comment: When I try to export without selecting a band first, exporting takes very long. This is probably because of memory issues, when doing the reduceRegions over all bands?

Answer (score 0):

To select bands from each image in the collection use `.select([bandsToSelect])` 
In your case, `no2Days.select('NO2_column_number_density')`

Regarding your question about null values, NO2 data has some masked out pixels. I zoomed to one area, see the [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1520c676fd6bc0f0ff6135c3f31359aa).