# Why does means not appear in the Feature Collections after applying a ee.Reducer.mean() through the image.reduceRegions

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

I am trying to aggregate the MODIS ET data into 1km by 1km grid squares. I have tried applying the ee.Reducer.means through the image.reduceRegions to get the mean value of MODIS-ET pixels within the grid square. However, the resultant Feature somehow did not include a resultant mean value for each feature (grid square).

```
var AWD = table // 1km by 1km grid feature collections across Ayerwady region in Myanmar;


var ETcollection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD16A2');

//print(ETcollection);

var ET_first = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD16A2/2001_01_01');

print(ET_first);
print('Scale:', ET_first.projection().nominalScale());

var ET = ET_first.select('ET');

print(ET);

var evapotranspirationVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 300.0,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'fcd163', '99b718', '66a000', '3e8601', '207401', '056201',
    '004c00', '011301'
  ],
};

Map.addLayer(AWD, {}, 'Ayerwady');
Map.centerObject(AWD,8);

Map.addLayer(ET.clipToBoundsAndScale({geometry:AWD,scale:463.3127165275}), evapotranspirationVis, 'ET');

var awdgrid = ee.FeatureCollection(table2);

Map.addLayer(awdgrid,{}, 'Grid');

var stats = ET.reduceRegions({
  collection: awdgrid,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 463.3127165275
});

print('1km mean', ee.Feature(stats.first()));

print('mean', ee.Feature(stats.limit({max:10, property: 'mean' }))); // there are no mean values in the mean column

function getCols(tableMetadata){
  print(tableMetadata.columns);
}

//stats.limit(0).evaluate(getCols);

Map.addLayer(stats.select('mean'),evapotranspirationVis,'1km');

var empty = ee.Image().byte();
var outline = empty.paint({
  featureCollection: stats,
  color:'mean'
});
//var palette = ['#000000', '#F6FD0C', '#FF9A00', '#FF0000'];

Map.addLayer(outline, evapotranspirationVis,'ET_1km'); // I could still visualise the 1km by 1km means
//Map.addLayer(grid);
```

I can't seem to find where I went wrong. Is there a way to retrieve the mean value of each grid square?

UPDATE

```
'1km mean'
Feature 000000000000000033e8 (Polygon, 5 properties)
type: Feature
id: 000000000000000033e8
geometry: Polygon, 10 vertices
properties: Object (5 properties)
id: 492075
bottom: 16.924260574
left: 94.205277649
right: 94.214277649
top: 16.933260574

'mean'
FeatureCollection (10 elements, 7 columns)
type: FeatureCollection
columns: Object (7 properties)
features: List (10 elements)
0: Feature 000000000000000034e2 (Polygon, 6 properties)
type: Feature
id: 000000000000000034e2
geometry: Polygon, 5 vertices
properties: Object (6 properties)
id: 503135
bottom: 15.979260574
left: 94.250277649
mean: 828.770462633452
right: 94.259277649
top: 15.988260574
```

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example with the table you are using? The code itself seems to work fine if I use a sample featurecollection [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4c3ec1ea5b31a01dd203f46b05494820)

Comment: I've updated the post I tried running the script again and I realised that it does work. After rearranging them in descending order, I was able to view mean ET values within the pixels. However, I never expected that pixels with no ET values would not have the 'mean' property appended to them (with a 0 value)

Comment: See solutions here:  [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355073/exporting-lst-median-values-of-a-time-series-in-google-ee-to-csv-file/355104#355104)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link!